# What is the overhead on PostAuthenticateRequest?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I am implementing a custom ticket system using the `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` method in my `global.asax` file (ASP.NET MVC). I'm wondering what the overhead for this kind of thing is - since it will deserialize some information on every request. It generates a cookie of around 1.8 kb, which is a ton - but is that a better alternative than frequent database trips?

### Information being deserialized

- User Id (int)
- Roles (string[])
- Email (string)
- Associated Ids (int[]) // (hard to describe what these are, but each user will have around 3 of them)

It seemed smarter to implement a custom `FormsAuthenticationTicket` system than to continuously do round-trips to the database based on `User.Identity.Name`. But I'm just worried that this constant deserialization is very inhibitive. But it looks something like this...

```
    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            string encTicket = authCookie.Value;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(encTicket))
            {
                // decrypt the ticket if possible.
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(encTicket);

                var userData = Deserializer.Deserialize(ticket);
                UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(userData);

                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the class being serialized as `UserData` in the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`.

```
[Serializable]
public class MembershipData
{
    public string Email
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string[] Roles
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int[] Ancillary
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have many applications out in the wild that do this exact thing - storing data in the userData portion of the forms authentication ticket. I don't have to deserialize as the data is just a comma-delimited list, but I imagine this won't be a bottleneck for you. You'll have to do some testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you measuring the performance but I would expect that the cookie approach will be faster than doing roundtrips to the database. You could also simplify the serialization and make it as fast as possible by using a comma delimited or some special character delimited string. Here is how I would rank different operations in terms of performance:

1. in-process communication
2. inter-process communication
3. inter-network communication

Comment: Even if the cookie is 1.8 kb in size, it's still better than the frequent round trips? I'm getting red flags from FireFox, Chrome, and Safari about the cookie size... but I can't think of any other way to store the relevant information I need. I can't rely on just putting it in the `Session`, that's as bad as just loading it into a cookie, and its prone to more problems. I can't really rely on caching it, as it needs to be tied to logins, and I using dependency injection just means round trips to the database more times.

Comment: To reduce the size of your cookie you could look at custom serialization for your ticket - I've heard good reviews for Google Protocol Buffers.

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is a bit old at this point and already has an accepted answer, but I'd like to throw in my thoughts and how we currently do things with a similar setup.

Originally, we were going through the same process you were and included a fair bit of user data in the cookie. This process did cut down on our database trips, but eventually we hit a bug wherein some users couldn't log in at all while others could. Turns out that the cookie was silently being dropped when it went over a certain size due to our serialized data.

Our current process is a two-tiered caching system instead. We store the user's database ID in the cookie as the `User.Identity.Name` and then on PostAuthenticateRequest, we try to retrieve the user info from a local ASP.net cache, falling back to a distributed Redis cache. The local cache is in-proc and stored for 15 seconds (so repeated requests don't require going across the wire to Redis). Redis cache is stored for a day, and invalidated on update. If both of those are misses, we then load the information from SQL Server.

We then drop that user information into a custom IPrincipal and everything works like a charm. This seems to work pretty well for us in a reasonably high-usage website.